# Python: Explanation of example... Why does this work?

Tags: python, multithreading, oop, class

I've been mucking around with python for a little while and I have recently come up with something involving multithreading...  without further ado... heres what I have...

```
import pythoncom
import wmi
import threading

class Info(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        c = wmi.WMI()
        detect = c.Win32_ComputerShutdownEvent.watch_for()
        detect()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Info().start()
    for process in c.Win32_Process(Name="something.exe"):
        result = process.Terminate()
```

So my question is... Why does this work?  It may be an overall question regarding the process of the inheritence of threading.Thread... but there is no start() def in the class Info() so why does the run def begin?

This is actually a pretty handy application I needed to use to stop an application that always seems to hang when windows shuts down... finding when the windows shutdown event happens was a bit of a headache but luckily tim golden's masterpiece saves the day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [it's defined in the parent](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start). Parent classes are checked for attributes if they're not found (or handled) in the child class.

Comment: Thanks, I totally should have read into that more, I've been toying with the Threading a bit and see now I need to implement Queue...  good info!

Answer (score 2):

Subclasses of `Thread` automatically call their `run()`, when you call `start()` on them. Start is defined in `Thread`.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#thread-objects)

> There are two ways to specify the activity: by passing a callable object to the constructor, or by overriding the run() method in a subclass.

and from docs on `start()`

> It arranges for the object’s run() method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you intent to wait the thread has ended before killing process ? 
If so:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    info = Info()
    info.start()
    info.join()
    for process in c.Win32_Process(Name="something.exe"):
        result = process.Terminate()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... its funny actually I have been having this issue with a different application where a seperate application created with TKinter is designed to run on an endless loop, listening to a port... its a long story... so this was originally designed to run builtin with that application and because the wmi module's watch() holds the application flow I just call this along with the other "something.exe" so once a windows shutdown is generated it says... whoops... kill something.exe and then there is no hung process.